# gst-plugin : how to add watch to cutter element

Tags: gstreamer

I have created a custom audio filter using gstreamer plugins `audiocheblimit` and `cutter` which will remove noise from the input mediapipeline and detect silence.

the problem which I am facing is how can I add a `wacth` to the `cutter` element in my `gst-plugin` project.

Comment: You don't need to use `gst_pad_push_event` to send events to kurento. Just a gobject signal. Why do you think that?

Comment: okay I will do that, but how can I add a wacth to the `cutter` element in my `gst-plugin` project ? `cutter` element doesnt give any `signal` which means I will have to add watch on the `bus` for `message` and I am not understanding how to get a `bus` inside the `gst-plugin`